# How to interpret Deep learning network architecture into a diagram?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network, diagram, deep-residual-networks

How to draw this Deep learning network architecture diagrams?

I'm using Faster R-CNN: R50-FPN.

Any ideas or tip to convert this to a diagram?

For this I used detectron2 framework with pytorch. But the output it is below, like text without image
I would like to transform this to a diagram. because it is more intuitive and easier to understand.

```
GeneralizedRCNN(
  (backbone): FPN(
    (fpn_lateral2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (fpn_output2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (fpn_lateral3): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (fpn_output3): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (fpn_lateral4): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (fpn_output4): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (fpn_lateral5): Conv2d(2048, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (fpn_output5): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (top_block): LastLevelMaxPool()
    (bottom_up): ResNet(
      (stem): BasicStem(
        (conv1): Conv2d(
          3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False
          (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
        )          )
      (res2): Sequential(
        (0): BottleneckBlock(
          (shortcut): Conv2d(
            64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            64, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (1): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
        )
        (2): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=64, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )            )          )
      (res3): Sequential(
        (0): BottleneckBlock(
          (shortcut): Conv2d(
            256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            256, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (1): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (2): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (3): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=128, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )            )          )
      (res4): Sequential(
        (0): BottleneckBlock(
          (shortcut): Conv2d(
            512, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (1): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (2): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (3): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (4): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (5): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=256, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=1024, eps=1e-05)
          )            )          )
      (res5): Sequential(
        (0): BottleneckBlock(
          (shortcut): Conv2d(
            1024, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=2048, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            1024, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=2048, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (1): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=2048, eps=1e-05)
          )            )
        (2): BottleneckBlock(
          (conv1): Conv2d(
            2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv2): Conv2d(
            512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=512, eps=1e-05)
          )
          (conv3): Conv2d(
            512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False
            (norm): FrozenBatchNorm2d(num_features=2048, eps=1e-05)
          )            )          )        )      )
  (proposal_generator): RPN(
    (anchor_generator): DefaultAnchorGenerator(
      (cell_anchors): BufferList()
    )
    (rpn_head): StandardRPNHead(
      (conv): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (objectness_logits): Conv2d(256, 3, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
      (anchor_deltas): Conv2d(256, 12, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    )      )
  (roi_heads): StandardROIHeads(
    (box_pooler): ROIPooler(
      (level_poolers): ModuleList(
        (0): ROIAlign(output_size=(7, 7), spatial_scale=0.25, sampling_ratio=0, aligned=True)
        (1): ROIAlign(output_size=(7, 7), spatial_scale=0.125, sampling_ratio=0, aligned=True)
        (2): ROIAlign(output_size=(7, 7), spatial_scale=0.0625, sampling_ratio=0, aligned=True)
        (3): ROIAlign(output_size=(7, 7), spatial_scale=0.03125, sampling_ratio=0, aligned=True)
      )        )
    (box_head): FastRCNNConvFCHead(
      (fc1): Linear(in_features=12544, out_features=1024, bias=True)
      (fc2): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
    )
    (box_predictor): FastRCNNOutputLayers(
      (cls_score): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=2, bias=True)
      (bbox_pred): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4, bias=True)
    )      )    )
```

Comment: Did you try [pytorchviz](https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: I thought about that, however I have trouble interpreting the layers

Comment: Well, I don't think it will be any easier with other tools to be honest.

Comment: For example, how can I identify the input layers according to what I uploaded?

Comment: It's `bottom_up.stem` as it has `3` input channels. Should be top most in the visualization graph as well I think.

Comment: How can I see the output layers? or the hidden layers with the connections?

Comment: Did you try `pytorchviz`? It will show you the blocks, bottom ones being output, while input at the top

Comment: I don't think you can see every connection and weight though + it would be kinda hard to read (how to show channels and kernels of convolution clearly in such network?)

Comment: Yes, But at least know what are the input, hidden and output layers? Using pytorchviz requires knowing weights and specific information